# Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Here is my component, I exported `Home` in my Home component at the end of the file. The code worked just fine in React Native but I'm currently porting it to expo and it stopped working. I have read also it has something to do with the imports but I don't have that many.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

import Home from './src/views/containers/home'
import Header from './src/sections/components/header'
import SuggestionList from './src/videos/containers/suggestion-list'
import CategoryList from './src/videos/containers/category-list'
import Player from './src/player/containers/player'

import API from './utils/api'
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  state = {
    suggestionList: [],
    categoryList: []
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    //some code
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Home> //Line 28
        <Header/>
        <Player/>
        <Text>Search</Text>
        <Text>Categories</Text>
        <CategoryList 
          list={this.state.categoryList}
        />
        <SuggestionList 
          list={this.state.suggestionList}
        />

      </Home>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error

```
Check the render method of `App`.

This error is located at:
in Home (at App.js:28)
in App (at withExpoRoot.js:20)
in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:19)
in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
in RCTView (at View.js:45)
in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
in RCTView (at View.js:45)
in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
```

Am I importing something wrong?

Home is just a wrapper

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Home extends Component {
    render(){
        return this.props.children
    }
}

export default Home;
```

The error was actually in the player, where I had a bad import but then it says that I got the same error but for my playPause component. In line 13

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    TouchableHighlight,
    StyleSheet,
    Platform,
} from 'react-native'

import Icon from '@expo/vector-icons'

function PlayPause(props) {
    return (

        <TouchableHighlight //line 13
            onPress={props.onPress}
            style={styles.container}
            underlayColor='rgba(255,255,255,.3)'
            hitSlop={{
                left: 5,
                top: 5,
                bottom: 5,
                right: 5
            }}
        >
            {
                props.isPaused ? <Icon size={20} color="#98ca3f" name={
                    Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-play' : 'md-play'
                  } /> : <Icon size={20} color="#98ca3f" name={
                    Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-pause' : 'md-pause'} />
            }
        </TouchableHighlight>
    )
}

export default PlayPause
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not exporting `Header` as default? (same as your other components it seems)

Comment: Yes, I'm exporting `Header` as default also. But the error is not there, I can actually delete the `{ }` from the header import

Comment: at least one of your imports is wrong. Maybe you forgot a `deault` or accidently added `{}` even if it is no default export?

Comment: Well if its a `default` export then you should import it as a `default`: `import Header from './src/sections/components/header'`

Comment: @messerbill I just double checked, I have export default `myClass` in every component I import there

Comment: do a console.log after each import and log it to have a look which one is undefined

Comment: @messerbill I just updated my question. I don't understand why the error is in a RN component

Comment: so please re-edit your question, remove your answer from it and readd it as an answer below if this was your problem.

Comment: But I'm still having the exact same error, just with another component

Comment: If you are using vscode (or almost every ide has it nowadays) try doing CTRL+click to see if it brings you to your component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@expo/vector-icons` does not default export `ICON`.

`@expo/vector-icons` uses `Ionicons` by default.

[about `@expo/vector-icons`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/icons/)

[image]

example

```js
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
...
  {
                props.isPaused ? <Ionicons size={20} color="#98ca3f" name={
                    Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-play' : 'md-play'
                  } /> : <Ionicons size={20} color="#98ca3f" name={
                    Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-pause' : 'md-pause'} />
            }
```

**`ICON`** is the prop of **`react-native-vector-icons`**

```js
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/dist/FontAwesome';
```